# Rails 4 nested_attributes update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm getting an error when updating only the nested.

What I'm doing:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.update(data_attributes: {race: 2})
```

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :data, inverse_of: :user, class_name: UserData, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :data
end

class UserData < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'user_data'
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :data
end
```

The error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'user_id' cannot be null: UPDATE `user_data` SET `user_id` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2015-01-05 10:27:47.680681' WHERE `user_data`.`id` = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update an existing `data` record, you have to include the object ID on the attributes_param:

```
user = User.find(1)
user_data_id = user.data.id
user.update(data_attributes: { id: user_data_id, race: '2' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `user_data` `table` has a `user_id` `column` which is not nullable. When you try to `update` a record, but you are not setting the value of `user_id`, thus it is `null`. And, as mentioned above, the `column` is not nullable. You need to either set it to be nullable, or to set it to the correct value.

Comment: I'm not changing the user_id to null. Since my association already have an user_id, why is Rails trying to change it?